# Creating directory structure through Mathematica

Tags: files-and-directories

Is there `mkdirs()` (make directory structure) equivalent in *Mathematica*?
I want to specify something like this : `dir1/dir2/dirn` and I want *Mathematica* to create the directory structure `dir1/dir2/dirn`

Comment: `CreateDirectory`?

Comment: `CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{"this", "that", "other"}]]` is an OS-independent way of creating a directory structure rooted in in the current directory. Evaluate `?*Directory*` to discover what sort of things Mathematica can do with directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a *Unix based OS* you can use `mkdir -p` with `Run`:

```
Run["mkdir -p ~/Projects/" <> 
  StringJoin @@ (ToString@StringForm["folder``/", #] & /@ Range@5)]
```

Then running `du ~/Projects` will show:

> ~/Projects/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5

If you are on *Windows* there should be the equivalent, I just don't know whether you need the `-p` or not.

---

Or as Yves Klett [said](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51046/creating-directory-structure-through-mathematica/51050#comment150531_51046):

```
CreateDirectory["~/Projects/" <> 
  StringJoin @@ (ToString@StringForm["folder``/", #] & /@ Range@5)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, there is something better than `mkdirs()`.

Some strings machinery first (nothing interesting):

```
spaceRiffledString = Composition[StringJoin, Riffle[Flatten@{##}, " "]&];

prefixStringViaSpace@s_String := spaceRiffledString@{s, #1}&
```

Directory creation handler:

```
createDirIfPossible =
Block[{CreateDirectory},
If[DirectoryQ@#,
Sequence @@ Transpose @
{ prefixStringViaSpace@"Directory" /@
  { "exists" ,     "created"     }
, {    #     , CreateDirectory@# } } // Evaluate]]&;
```

(An obsessive nod to D.R.Y. on my side.)

Map *Mathematica* native tree structure to file system:

```
createDirTree[address___, dir_String@subDirs___] :=
Map[createDirTree[address, dir, #]&, dir@subDirs, Heads -> True]

createDirTree[address___, _?AtomQ] :=
createDirIfPossible@FileNameJoin@{address}
```

Directories are represented as `"dirName"[]`, and `"fileName"` without empty sublist is reserved for files. It's tedious to type `[]` when we know we need a pure directory tree so let's add a converter for convenience:

```
openAtoms = Replace[#, a_?AtomQ :> a[], {1, \[Infinity]}]&;
```

Error-checking for trees (not a perfect one, though):

```
stringTreeQ@expr_ :=
MatchQ[
  Replace[
    Cases[expr, _?AtomQ|_?AtomQ[]
    , {0, \[Infinity]}, Heads -> True]
  , s_String[] :> s, {1}]
, {__String}]
```

Finally,

```
Options@CreateDirectoryTree = {"Output Form" -> OpenerView};

CreateDirectoryTree[ tree_?stringTreeQ
                   , root:_String:$HomeDirectory
                   , OptionsPattern[]] :=
createDirTree@openAtoms@root@tree //.
If[OptionValue@"Output Form" === OpenerView
,  { {msg_String, addr_String}[] :> msg <> ": " <> addr
   , {msg_String, addr_String}@sub__ :>
     OpenerView[{{msg, addr}[], Column@{sub}}, False]}
,  {}]
```

(The `//. …` part is merely pretty printing.)

Try it:

```
CreateDirectoryTree @
"example"[
  "Beatles"[
    "Harrison"@"George",
    "Lennon",
    "McCartney",
    "Starr"],
  "Spam"@"Eggs"@"Cheese shop"]
```

If some directories exist, it doesn't produce errors, merely messages.

It doesn't take much effort to additionally parse the result with `Button`'s to enrich it with immediate links to corresponding directories.

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised the in-house method has not been made to an answer:

```
CreateDirectory["this/that/other", CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]
```

Or the OS-independent way (as Stephen Luttrell has pointed out in a comment):

```
CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin@{"this", "that", "other"}, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]
```